# SoapClient::__call() error inside Payment::capture()

Tags: magento2, soap

Trying to implement custom payment using SOAP.
Payment system has working examples for php5 https://shop.nets.eu/web/partners/sample-code.

Soap works fine if I run this samples as plain PHP, but inside magento Soap fails.

When I send payment confirmation on checkout I Recieve error from magento REST:

```
http://mat24.dev/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/62398ebea871c954c98044c1fbe1da1f/payment-information

Status Code:400 Bad Request

{"message":"Unable to place order. Please try again later."}
```

Code fails at this string

```
$OutputParametersOfRegister = $client->__call()
```

Inside capture method I debugged all information and everything is ok, but I cannot see whats going on when I use Soap::__call()

My capture method is approximately looks like this:

```
public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {

        try {
            $merchantId = $this->getConfigData('merchant');
            $token = $this->getConfigData('token');
            $wsdl = $this->getConfigData('wsdl'); 
            $terminal = $this->getConfigData('terminal'); 


            $InputParametersOfRegister = array
            (
                "token"      => $token,
                "merchantId" => $merchantId,
                "request"    => $RegisterRequest
            );

            $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl,
                    ['trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true]);


            $this->log->info("P A Y M E N T  before __call"); //this logging is visible
            // Following string causes some error
            $OutputParametersOfRegister = $client->__call('Register', ["parameters" => $InputParametersOfRegister]);
            $RegisterResult = $OutputParametersOfRegister->RegisterResult;

            $this->log->info("P A Y M E N T  after __call"); // this logging is invisible
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->log->error('PAYMENT ERROR : ' . $e->getCode() . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment capturing error.'));
            }
    }
```

Please, any ideas how to debug it or what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your soap call into `try and catch` construction to find a reason of your error.
This can be done in the follows way:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, ['trace' => true]);
try {
    // use client to call some soap method
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    // handle exception message
}
```

This construction allows to do next two things:

1. You can get exception message -> `$e->getMessage()` and exception details `$e->detail`.
2. The `trace` option allows seeing details of your `$client` request. For example, if you use xdebug and set break point in the catch block, you can get request and response details: `$client->__last_request` and `$client->__last_response`, which allow you to find reason of your problem

Comment: Thanx. That's a correct answer as I solve this problem before. Actually I placed $client->__call('Register', ["parameters" => $InputParametersOfRegister]); into try-catch and it works. I recieve an error in log, but when I used try-catch for whole code it breaks after $client->__call and don't display error.

Answer (score 0):

Your request parameters may be getting stripped if they don't comply with what is described in the WSDL.

For more info on this look here: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php

Comment: parameters comply with wsdl. Have a look the samples. There is everything that works fine. Here is wsdl that you can look faster https://test.epayment.nets.eu/Netaxept.svc?wsdl